# Почему на десктопах браузеры победили приложения, а на смартфонах наоборот приложения победили браузеры?

Tags: браузер, дизайн, веб-дизайн, мобильные-приложения

Например на десктопах браузеры и соц. сети победили мессенджеры (ICQ и др.). А на смартфонах наоборот приложения победили браузеры (мессенджеры, приложения соц. сетей, платежные приложения и др.). Может быть дело в простоте установки по сравнению с установкой на десктопе? Или в том что первое время сайты не были оптимизированы для мобильных экранов и у пользователей возник негатив к браузеру на телефоне?

Comment: ваш вопрос закроют как слшком общий, но и в том и в другом случае в легковесных приложениях "побеждают" в смысле "больше" -  веб-технологии (html/js) поскольку больше кодеров / нет потребности в высокой скорости, зачастую современное веб приложение это, по сути,  браузер под прикрытием

Comment: "на десктопах браузеры и соц. сети победили мессенджеры" - кто вам сказал? Нет ничего удобней отдельных клиентов, даже для такого угрёбища, как slack. Не говоря уж о скайпах, ICQ-жаберах и прочих. Конечно, если это нормальные клиенты (типа Gajim или Pidgin), а не то развесистое-квипообразное, что под виндами цветёт. И - да, те же VK и FB тоже в клиентах, во всяком личная переписка (XMPP рулит). И нафиг не нужно браузер постоянно перед глазами держать. Подтвержено мной и практически всеми моими конактами :)

Comment: Потому что веб изначально создан для десктопов и под смартфоны только адаптируется. И обратно, браузеры на смартфонах пока далеки от совершенства.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что HTML5 приложения дико тормозят на мобильных устройствах.
Откройте web.telegram.org в браузере мобильного телефона и сравните с комфортом для глаз в самом приложении.
Хотя вроде несложное приложение для HTML5.

Даже такой гигант как FaceBook во славу тенденции сначала начал делать свое мобильное приложение на HTML5, но потом отказался от затеи ввиду обозначенной проблемы и перешел на нативное приложение.
https://habrahabr.ru/post/151337/

Comment: "сравните с комфортом для глаз" - не совсем понял, поясните.

Comment: Когда нажимаешь на чат, а телефон секунд 10 "думает". Это вызывает крайний дискомфорт. И при этом у меня например довольно таки производительный телефон, а что будет с людьми у которых бюджетные или даже среднего класса телефоны Android? Страшно представить. Пока HTML5 не дает вменяемой производительности - использовать его нецелесообразно для мобильных приложений. Ну или ждем dart, он может спасти ситуацию, если будет так же хорош, как его анонсируют.